# When does SQL SELECT statements throw exceptions?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, select

TSQL here. Specifically Server 2008(literally just upgraded)

Concerning stored procedures: Try/Catch

I was trying to make a list of cases when a Select Statement will throw an exception. The ones I can think of are syntax related(includes null variables) and divide by zero. I'm only guessing there are just a whole boat load of them for `Insert/Alter` and `Create/Truncate`.

If you happen to know of a good source link, that would be great.

This question came up when I was reading this exhaustive blog post about error handling for SQL server. It's titled for SQL Server 2000, but I think most of it still applies.

**edit**

Sorry, I meant to link this earlier. . .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175920(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: It might be nice to include a link to the exhaustive blog post.

Comment: You won't have read about TRY/CATCH in SQL Server 2000. It was introduced with SQL Server 2005... And do you mean http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to include that link. @gbn: Yeah, the blog post I'm linking has a bunch of if/elses.  I was going to reconcile that with try/catch.  Mainly, I don't want to catch exceptions I'm not willing to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside for compile ("didnt' run") errors, you have *at least* these runtime errors

- arithmetic errors
  These change based on various SET statement
  Example: [get sql server to warn about truncation / rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662001/get-sql-server-to-warn-about-truncation-rounding/6662061#6662061)
- overflow errors
  example: one of the rows overflows smallint in some calculation
- CAST errors
  eg you try ISNUMERIC in a WHERE or CASE and try to cast 'bob^' or 1.23 to int
  See [Why use Select Top 100 Percent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622878/why-use-select-top-100-percent/1623240#1623240)

However, you'd always want to use TRY/CATCH though, surely...?

Comment: That link was real good.  The syntax and sematics of SQL/stored procedures aren't too complicated, so I'm going to put some time in learning proper error handling.

Comment: @surfasb: see my answer here please then. You can remove the transaction stuff for read only procs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139 also, most folk don't tend to catch individual errors. It fails or it runs. Unless you need patterns like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593870/select-insert-version-of-an-upsert-is-there-a-design-pattern-for-high-concurre/3594328#3594328 (nested try/catch)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to gbn's post, you can also get locking errors like lock wait timeouts and deadlocks.

If you are referencing #Temp tables, you can get "Invalid object name '#Temp'" errors, because these are unbound until the statement executes.

If you are in READ UNCOMMITTED or WITH (NOLOCK), you can get error: 601 - "Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement."

If your code runs .NET code, you would probably get exceptions from there.

If your code selects from a remote server, you could a whole different set of errors about connections.

Comment: If you do **anything** over a remote connection, then all bets are off. . .